# android Bluetooth exception on receiving DISCOVERY_FINISHED

Tags: android, exception, bluetooth

I am having a problem in conducting a Bluetooth scan periodically. What should happen if a selected device went out of scan range after it was successfully scanned before and in range, Play the alarm and vibrate.

But for some reason after the first time it goes out of range and notifies me successfully, the following scan fails with an exception :

```
10-27 13:32:42.189: W/MediaPlayer(30256): info/warning (1, 902)
10-27 13:32:42.199: D/MediaPlayer(30256): start() in
10-27 13:32:42.219: D/MediaPlayer(30256): start() out
10-27 13:32:42.249: I/MediaPlayer(30256): Info (1,902)
10-27 13:32:55.091: D/AndroidRuntime(30256): Shutting down VM
10-27 13:32:55.091: W/dalvikvm(30256): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ad9228)
10-27 13:32:55.101: D/Process(30256): killProcess, pid=30256
10-27 13:32:55.101: D/Process(30256): dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
10-27 13:32:55.101: D/Process(30256): java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:599)
10-27 13:32:55.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30256): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-27 13:32:55.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30256): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent {         act=android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_FINISHED flg=0x10 } in com.moali.blue.service.MyService$1@40da2270
10-27 13:32:55.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:794)
10-27 13:32:55.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-27 13:32:55.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-27 13:32:55.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
10-27 13:32:55.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
10-27 13:32:55.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 13:32:55.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-27 13:32:55.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-27 13:32:55.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-27 13:32:55.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-27 13:32:55.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30256): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-27 13:32:55.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at com.moali.blue.service.MyService$1.onReceive(MyService.java:107)
10-27 13:32:55.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:781)
10-27 13:32:55.101: E/AndroidRuntime(30256):    ... 9 more
10-27 13:32:55.111: D/Process(30256): android.os.Process.killProcess(Process.java:791)
10-27 13:32:55.111: D/Process(30256): com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:104)
10-27 13:32:55.111: D/Process(30256): java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
10-27 13:32:55.111: D/Process(30256): java.lang.ThreadGroup.unca ughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
10-27 13:32:55.111: D/Process(30256): dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**My Code and Reciever as follows :**

```
    public void startVibrate()
{

        //Set the pattern for vibration   
        long pattern[]={0,200,100,300,400};

        //Start the vibration
        //start vibration with repeated count, use -1 if you don't want to repeat the vibration
        Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);

        try {

            mr = MediaPlayer.create(MyService.this, alert);
            mr.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                    mr.reset();
                    mr.release();

                    vibrator.cancel();

                }
            });


        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        vibrator.vibrate(pattern,0);
        mr.start();

}

protected void discover() {

    if(bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering())
    bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

    bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();      
}







private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        // When discovery finds a device
        if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)) {          
           BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
           String sDevice = device.getName();
           if(!sDevice.equals(null) && sDevice.equalsIgnoreCase(selected)){
                matchTo=device;
                inRange= true;
                if(bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering())
                bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
           }
        }else if(action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED)){
                if(!matchTo.equals(null)){
                    if(inRange){
                        inRange=false;
                    }
                    else{
                        matchTo=null;
                        startVibrate();

                    }
                }
                discover();                 
         }

    }

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if matchTo object is valid, but your syntax is incorrect.
To check if the object is valid (not null) you can't call objects' methods (e.g. **equals**).

Instead of:

```
if(!matchTo.equals(null)){
```

use:

```
if (matchTo != null) {
```

Comment: You know what it was like that and i changed ages ago.. and i forgot i did... thanks for the heads up.. works like a charm